# Jenkins: Copy data from slave to slave

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

let's say we have got the following scenario:

1. I have two slaves on Jenkins: S-1 und S-2.
2. I have two Build Jobs BJ-1 und BJ-2. (BJ-1 is running on S-1, BJ-2 on S-2.)
3. BJ-1 generates data in his workspace
4. BJ-2 needs the data created bey BJ-1 in his own workspace

How can i solve this problem WITHOUT copy all the data to my master. I know i can copy the data of BJ-1 on S-1 to my master server, once the job is done and i also know i can download the data to S-2 before BJ-2 runs. But as you see i have to copy them to my Master.

**The question:** Is there a way to directly copy the data from S-1 to S-2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Best way to achieve this is to archive your generated data in the post build steps in BJ-1 and copy then artifact to BJ-2 workspace.

**BJ-1**

Archiving artifacts is built in to Jenkins and allows you to define a file set to be available as part of the build results. Extend BJ-1 to configure what data should be archived [image: BJ-1 configuration example]. With that the archived data is available for further use.

**BJ-2**

In order to pick up the archived artifacts from another job you will need to install the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin). In BJ-2 you add a new build step to copy artifact from a named build - with that any files matching the configured pattern will be copied into the current job's workspace. [image: BJ-2 configuration example] With that you can access any kind of artifacts across jobs/slave nodes etc.

Comment: when i am using "Archivin Artifacts"... will they be stored in the job's workspace on the Slave or on the Master server? Because if they are stored on the Master i did not made any steps forward ;)

Comment: it doesn't matter where they are stored. your step forward is that you utilize Jenkins Plugin Copy Artifact  in your second job to retrieve whatever you have archived in first job. Rather than operating on file system level you utilize Jenkins provided functionality to interact between jobs.

Comment: I found that the described method actually moves the artifact over to the master, then copies it back to the slave.